# dependency injection issues factory object null in angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to learn angular and having some difficulty with injecting my factory class called 'courseService' into my controller called CoursesController(coursesController.js). It does not always instantiate. This is how I set it up now:

```
(function () {

 var CoursesController = function ($scope, $location, $filter, $routeParams, courseService) {
 CoursesController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$routeParams', 'courseService'];

});
```

To illustrate this problem I created a plunker sample:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/W9OmBs7w8RlV55EWngT1?p=preview
```

When you run the sample the courseService is instantiated fine then. I can see this in the chromeconsole (sources, run.plnkr.co)

[image]

I click the button 'Add Course' which will take me to the courseEditController. When I then click on View Courses which will take me back to the coursesController the courseService is undefined. See image below. The funny thing is when I hit CTRL+ F5 on the courses.html then it is fine. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: anyone? where are all these smart developers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the plunker sample, I got the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$injector/unpr?p0=courseFilterFilterProvider%20%3C-%20courseFilterFilter
```

Unknown provider "courseFilter"

In the file "coursesController.js", the following code

```
function filterCourses(filterText) {
        $scope.filteredCourses = $filter("courseFilter")($scope.courses, filterText);
        $scope.filteredCount = $scope.filteredCourses.length;
}
```

However, the "courseFilter" has not been defined as a filter in any file.
Define it as

```
var courseFilter = function () {
    return function (input, filterText) {
       //filter code goes here
    };
};
angular.module('CoursesApp').filter('courseFilter', courseFilter);
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: yes I fixed this one but I still have the same bug:(

Comment: What exactly is the error that is shown? Please post that.



Also, check the order of dependencies in the CoursesController. It should be 

var CoursesController = function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $location, $filter, courseService) {
 CoursesController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$routeParams',
'$location', '$filter', 'courseService'];